# Querying on a virtual property in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a virtual property in my mongoose schema, I would like to know if I can query my documents using this property.

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
  number: {type: Number, required: true},
  name: {type: Date, required: true}
});

PersonSchema.virtual('capitalCaseName').get(function () {
  return this.name.toUpperCase();
});
...
Person.find({"capitalCaseName": "DANIEL"}).exec();
...
```

Comment: Why not use a regex query that's case insensitive?

Comment: I made my example easy to understand. Thats not the real model

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No, you can't.  Mongoose virtual properties only exist in the Mongoose model representation of documents, not in MongoDB itself where the query is performed.

Any field you need to query against must be defined in the schema as a non-virtual field and persisted to the database.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if it were possible?

Comment: And does exist an alternative solution?

Comment: Yes, an alternative solution would be to use [$where](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) or [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), which allow you to manually "compute" a virtual property and create a more customised query.

Comment: It would be nice, but think about it. Virtuals doesn't exists in the real database. If mongoose could query using the virtual property, you are making it calculate the virtual field for each document (all the documents), and then, will compare the result. It would be a pain in ass for the database engine, and will slow down your code a lot.

Comment: @newman It wouldn't be nice because then you'd be running queries on the application layer(node) which is NOT designed to run efficient queries on data instead of the DB layer (MongoEngine) which IS designed to run efficient queries on data